# opening Python file directly in VS code vs opening folder in VS code (images not displayed)

Tags: python, image, pyinstaller, pyqt6

I am new in this and I must be doing something wrong. When I open folder in VS code and execute main.py, all works fine. When I open main.py file directly in VS code (or if I use pyinstaller for packaging) images are not displayed at all (although, included in distribution folder together with exe file). All images are in jpeg format (but same is true for other formats too) and in the same folder as main.py.

Example code:

self.ui.label.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(image.jpg); border-top-left-radius: 50px;")

I also tried url(./image.jpg) - same result. Image is displayed only when I open folder in VS code.

I successfully solved above problem with construction of relative path to the image, but this only works for QPixmap (I am using PyQt6). Following code does not work for me:

```
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    image = os.path.join(current_dir, 'image.jpg')
    self.ui.label.setStyleSheet(f"border-image: url({image}); border-top-left-radius: 50px;")
```

Comment: The problem is most probably caused by missing quotes around the path: change to `url('{image}')`.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding quotes does not help. I think that adding quotes actually removes value of image variable. Thanks for answering and trying to help

Comment: No, it does not, because quotes are not part of the formatting. At least, as long as you used them properly. I cannot talk about VSCode, but ensure that the distribution also includes all image plugins: see the contents of the `plugins/imageformats` directory, if it doesn't exist, you need to add those files to the list.

Comment: Is the problem that images are not shown or not found? If not shown, make sure that you're using the same virtual environment. A folder is its own workspace, which can have its own virtual environment assigned. Opening a file directly uses the current / default virtual environment. If you get a file not found error, the reason could be that the current working directory is different from when you open the folder as the workspace.